# Minecraft username / uuid from accesstoken

Tags: c#, minecraft

I can get `accesstoken` but I don't know how to get `username` and `uuid` from `accesstoken`, when I login it's gave me something like that

> {"accessToken":"123","clientToken":"123","selectedProfile":{"id":"123","name":"playername"},"availableProfiles":[{"id":"123","name":"playername"}]}

Thanks!

```
private vstrong textoid Signin_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        bool isSignedIn = false;
        if (isSignedIn == true)
        {
            var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://authserver.mojang.com/invalidate");
            request.ContentType = "application/json";
            request.Method = "POST";

            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                dynamic json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
                {
                    accessToken = Settings.Default.accessToken,
                    clientToken = Settings.Default.clientToken
                });
            }
            Settings.Default.UUID = null;
            Settings.Default.accessToken = null;
            Settings.Default.clientToken = null;
        }
        else
        {
            var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://authserver.mojang.com/authenticate");
            httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
            httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                dynamic json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
                {
                    agent = new
                    {
                        name = "Minecraft",
                        version = 1
                    },
                    username = email.Text,
                    password = password.Password
                });
                streamWriter.Write(json);
                streamWriter.Flush();
                streamWriter.Close();
            }

            var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                ACCESS_TOKEN = result;
            } 
        }
    }
     catch (WebException)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Login failed. Invalid username or password.");
    }
}
string ACCESS_TOKEN;

public string GetAccessToken()
{
    return ACCESS_TOKEN;
}
```

Comment: Any reason why you expect minecraft to send you the usename/password in clear text back again?

Comment: wat do u mean by that i just login using emal/pass then mojang send me accesstoken

Answer (score 0):

That is a JSON response, which you will need to deserialize to use most effectively. You can do this with the following code:

```
var loginResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LoginResponse>(result);
```

Now, the MinecraftLoginResponse will need to be a class you create yourself, unless there is a library that you are using for this. JSON consists of variable value combinations, the values after the ':', separated by commas. {} denote an object, and [] a collection.

In the minecraft response, you have two objects; the response itself, and then the Profile object. C# code of this response is:

```
public class Profile
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class LoginResponse
{
    public string accessToken { get; set; }
    public string clientToken { get; set; }
    public Profile selectedProfile { get; set; }
    public List<Profile> availableProfiles { get; set; }
}
```

I made the above by running the example response through [this website](http://json2csharp.com/), then removing the SelectedProfile and AvailableProfile as these are, logically, going to be the same thing. (Selected will be one of the available profiles).

Comment: thx u very much, how can i get name on settings like this  
Settings.Default.name = name;?

Comment: Settings.Default.name = loginResponse.selectedProfile.name;

I've also changed the above answer to show you need to assign the result from the deserialize to an object.